# This specific str.replace() in Python with BeautifulSoup isn't working

Tags: python, string, replace, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to automate a task that occurs roughly monthly, which is adding a hyperlink to a page that looks like:

```
2013: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012: Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011: Jan Feb Mar ...
```

Whenever we get a new document for that month, we add the

```
<a href="document_001.pdf">Jul</a>
```

tags around it.

So I'm using BeautifulSoup in Python.  You can see below that I'm picking out the HTML "p" tag that contains this data and doing a replace() on the first month that it finds (finds Month using the reverse dictionary I created, and the third parameter of replace() indicates to only do the first one it finds).

```
# Modify link in hr.php:
hrphp = open('\\\\intranet\\websites\\infonet\\hr\\hr.php', 'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(hrphp) # Parsing with BeautifulSoup
Months = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)} # Creates a reverse dictionary for month abbreviation lookup by month number, ie. "print Months[07]" will print "Jul"

print hrphp+"\n\n\n\n\n"  # DEBUGGING: Compare output before
hrphp = hrphp.replace(
    str(soup.findAll('p')[4]), 
    str(soup.findAll('p')[4]).replace(
        Months[int(InterlinkDate[1][-5:-3])], 
        "<a href=\""+FilenameNewsletter+"\">"+Months[int(InterlinkDate[1][-5:-3])]+"</a>", 
        1), 
    1
)
print hrphp # DEBUGGING: Compare output after
```

See how it's a nested replace()?  The logic seems to work out fine, but for some reason it doesn't actually change the value.  Earlier in the script I do something similar with the Months[] dictionary and str.replace() on a segment of the page, and that works out, although it doesn't have a nested replace() like this nor does it search for a block of text using soup.findAll().

Starting to bang my head around on the desk, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some of the example file hr.php? I want to be able to test my solution to help you debug this code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that modifying `hr.php` so that it renders appropriately isn't a viable option?

Comment: @IamReck - Yes, later this afternoon; running to meetings!

Comment: @JonClements - Actually that's not totally out of the question.  It requires jumping through some more hoops and getting my supervisor to make the changes, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you end up doing with the code `str(soup.findAll('p')[4]).replace` is just replacing the values that are found in a string representation of the results in `soup.findAll('p')[4]`, which will more than likely differ from the string in `hrphp` because ["Beautiful Soup gives you Unicode"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) after it parses.

Beautiful Soups documentation holds the answer. Have a look at the [Changing Attribute Values section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree).

Comment: There were reasons I had to convert that stuff to string, it was causing some sort of error when doing the replace() ... Will have more info later this afternoon, running to meetings, sorry!

Comment: I played with it for a couple hours.  You were right, I had to change what was being searched, soup'd, and typecasted into str().  Finally got it to work.

Comment: Is my answer sufficient for someone with the same question as you to use to solve it? If not, please edit it for posterity.

Comment: I believe so, since the stuff in my code I changed was so specific... someone else's code will be specific to them as well, but they can extrapolate the idea of figuring out what HTML code is being searched and compared based on your answer like I did.